# subscribe event getting called while setting value

Tags: html, knockout.js, observable

I have select list in my html binded to observable array

```
 <select data-bind="options: myData, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedId"></select>
```

When i load my page i set value to observable `selectedId`

But when i set value it immediately calls its subscribe event

```
  selectedId.subscribe(function (row) {
      // some logic for retrieving data
  });
```

I dont want subscribe event to call when value is being set programatically but only want to call when user selects something from list.

Is it possible to do? Cant find any good examples.

**Update1**
i set value to my observable `selectedId` in this way

```
selectedId(ko.utils.arrayFirst(data(), function(item) {
                    return item.id=== 5;
}));
```

I think because of this its firing subscribe event

Comment: How do you set the value of `selectedId`?

Comment: `But when i set value it immediately calls its subscribe event`: Of course it does. The value changed. How about not hooking up the subscribe until *after* you've set the initial value?

Comment: @MattBurland how can we do it?

Comment: @haim770 i set it like selectedId(somevalue)

Comment: You put the line `selectedId(somevalue)` before the line `selectedID.subscribe(//...`

Comment: @MattBurland yes it put it before

Comment: @Happy: Then I don't understand the problem. If you set it before subscribing, there is no way it can fire the subscribe event. Post some minimal code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the initial value before you actually subscribe, then you shouldn't get a subscription event firing. For example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.selectedID = ko.observable();
  self.selectedID(10); // this won't fire the event because we haven't subscribed yet

  self.selectedID.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert("value changed by user");
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="number" data-bind="value: selectedID" />
```

Now if you want to solve the general case, where the value might change programmatically later and you don't want the `subscribe` to fire then, you might want to have a flag that you can use to simply skip the processing of the `subscribe` handler. Something like:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.selectedID = ko.observable();
  self.selectedID(10); // this won't fire the event because we haven't subscribed yet

  var _skipNotification = false; // this tells us whether or not we should process subscribe

  // putting this logic in a function makes it easier if you have multiple places 
  // where you need to programmatically set the id.
  function setSelectedID(value) {
    _skipNotification = true;
    self.selectedID(value);
    _skipNotification = false;
  }

  self.selectedID.subscribe(function(value) {
    if (!_skipNotification) {
      alert("value changed by user");
    }
  });

  self.changeProgrammatically = function() {
    setSelectedID(1);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="number" data-bind="value: selectedID" />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: changeProgrammatically" value="change programmatically" />
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/84/) fixed to use the technique above. A local variable `_skipNotification` is defined in the view model and checked in the subscribe event. Then the `importData` function that is called from the mouse click looks like this:

```
 this.importData = function () {
     skipNotification = true;
     self.selectedGroup(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableGroups(), function (val) {
         //debugger;
         return val.GroupId == 8;
     }));
     skipNotification = false;

     console.log("Lets see if it hits me first");
 };
```

This will set the `selectedGroup` without causing the body of the `selectedGroup.subscribe` to execute. Note that as a result the `selectedGroupId` doesn't get set so your one span will still say `You have chosen Nothing` despite the fact that something is selected in the drop-down. I'm not sure if that was what you were actually going for, but it seems pretty misleading. Especially since the only way to now get it to correctly read `You have chosen Football Team` is to select something else first and then reselect `Football Team`.

Comment: @Happy: You update doesn't make the slightest difference. Post some code that *actually demonstrates the problem*

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/82/   There is some issue with fiddle. Getting undefined error. This is what i am almost doing in my code. I am quite sure when you click importData button in fiddle then the subscribe event will be called

Comment: @Happy: I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/83/) to fix your undefined error. You never assigned `self`. Your problem can exactly be solved by what I had in my second solution. I suggest you edit your question to include what you have in the fiddle because your initial question was completely unclear. You are hooking up the subscribe handler when the view model is constructed but not setting `selectedGroup` until later in response to an event.